# Close-out in practice: default settlements and counterparty models

Tags: cva, default, default-risk, counterparty-risk, fva

Any model on counterparty risk for derivative contracts needs to make an assumption on the **close-out convention**, that is the rule used to determine at which value a defaulted derivative transaction between two parties $A$ and $B$ is settled.

Broadly speaking, the literature is usually split between two different close-out assumptions: **risk-free close-out**, that is the defaulted contract is settled at its risk-free value neglecting any implied counterparty-related risk factors; or a **substitution** or **risky close-out** in which the settlement value includes counterparty-related risks "*as computed from
a third market player that is eager to become the counterparty of the survived party for the
residual deal, replacing the defaulted one*" (Brigo and Morini, 2010). From a modelling perspective, risk-free close-out is usually easier to deal with because it induces linear valuation PDEs, whereas risky close-out almost inescapably results in non-linear or semi-linear PDEs.

**What is the actual practice among market practitioners when closing out a defaulted deal? What close-out assumption is usually made in counterparty models deployed in production environments?**

While I am aware of what my institution does, I am wondering what the general practice is. Ideally, publicly available sources on this topic would be welcomed.

**References**

Brigo, Damiano and Morini, Massimo (2010). "Dangers of Bilateral Counterparty Risk: the fundamental impact of closeout conventions", available at SSRN: https://dx.doi.org/10.2139/ssrn.1709370.